# Can I configure a network interface (eth0, eth1, etc.) to be down by default, but still be available?

Tags: networking, server

Can I configure a network interface (eth0, eth1, etc.) to be down by default, but still be available?

I would like my eth0 interface to be "down" after a fresh boot. With the option of using ifup eth0 from the command line to bring it up later.

Comment: Is this on a system with or without network manager?

Comment: ubuntu server 12.04, without network manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/network/interfaces` is repsonsible for getting it up.

Comment out `auto eth0` (add a `#` in front of it) and it will not start on boot.

Comment: Can I still use "ifup eth0" at the command prompt?

Comment: Yes of course! That was the whole idea ;) 1 thing: if this does not work networkmanager might be interfering (but I assume you are using a server and not a server with a desktop)